# Undefined control sequence in newtheoremstyle

Tags: theorems

I have the following piece of LaTeX code:

```
\newtheoremstyle{quest}
    {20pt} % space above
    {\topset} % space below
    {} % body font
    {} % indentation
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {} % punctuation after theorem head
    {0pt} % space after theorem head
    {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)} \\} % head spec
\theoremstyle{quest}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
```

The compiler complains that the `% head spec` line has "undefined control sequence" but I cannot figure out what is wrong with that line.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 4):

In the second argument you have `\topset` (with a "t") and it should be `\topsep` (with a "p"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{quest}
    {20pt} % space above
    {\topsep} % space below
    {} % body font
    {} % indentation
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {} % punctuation after theorem head
    {0pt} % space after theorem head
    {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)} \\} % head spec
\theoremstyle{quest}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
test
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, you can achieve the same style in a simpler way:

```
\newtheoremstyle{quest}
    {20pt} % space above
    {\topsep} % space below
    {} % body font
    {} % indentation
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {} % punctuation after theorem head
    {\newline} % space after theorem head
    {} % head spec
```

You could have detected the problem yourself looking at the error message produce with the original code:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \topset 

l.12     {}
            % head spec
?
```

The last command in the line following the "! Undefined control sequence." part is the problematic command; in this case, `\topset`.